# Need help saving input fields for Security Deposit plugin in WC Vendors page

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, customization, input

I'm having trouble integrating some input fields from a WooCommerce Security Deposits plugin (https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-security-deposits-wordpress-plugin/19988389) into the frontend of my website.

I'm attempting to input the fields into a WC Vendors Pro product editing form so users on my website can adjust their security deposit value etc.

I have the following input for the security deposits and it saves it to the product metadata through the function in the second block of code.

```
<?php woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
                        'id' => '_wc_security_deposits_enable' ,
                        'label' => __( 'Collect security deposit' , 'woocommerce-security-deposits' ) ,
                        'description' => __( 'Enable this to collect a security deposit for this product' , 'woocommerce-security-deposits' ) ,
                        'desc_tip' => true ) );
                    ?>
```

Here is the function:

```
public function process_product_meta( $post_id ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

        $enable_security_deposit = isset( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_enable' ] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

        $amount_type = ( isset( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_amount_type' ] ) &&
            ( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_amount_type' ] === 'fixed' ||
                $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_amount_type' ] === 'percent' ) ) ?
            $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_amount_type' ] : 'fixed';

        $amount = isset( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_deposit_amount' ] ) &&
        is_numeric( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_deposit_amount' ] ) ? floatval( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_deposit_amount' ] ) : 0.0;

        if( $amount <= 0 ){
            $enable_security_deposit = 'no';
            $amount = '';
        }

        $multiply_by_persons = isset( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_multiply_per_persons' ] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        $multiply_by_quantity = isset( $_POST[ '_wc_security_deposits_multiply_by_quantity' ] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

        $product->update_meta_data( '_wc_security_deposits_enable' , $enable_security_deposit );
        $product->update_meta_data( '_wc_security_deposits_multiply_by_quantity' , $multiply_by_quantity );
        $product->update_meta_data( '_wc_security_deposits_amount_type' , $amount_type );
        $product->update_meta_data( '_wc_security_deposits_deposit_amount' , $amount );

        if( $product->is_type( 'booking' ) && $product->has_persons() ){
            $product->update_meta_data( '_wc_security_deposits_multiply_per_persons' , $multiply_by_persons );
        }
        $product->save();

    }
```

I have tried creating a field in the seperate page in the WP Vendors plugin that mimics the checkbox for enabling security deposits, however I am unable to obviously make it stick to the product metadata - it's merely visual and does not function properly.

Any help is hugely appreciated, I am not a PHP programmer and have been stuck on this problem for a long time.

Thanks so much

Comment: Please see my documentation here: https://docs.wcvendors.com/knowledge-base/adding-a-custom-field-for-products/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a custom field to the product-edit form, saving is done automatically if you correctly format your input id.

```
WCVendors_Pro_Form_Helper::input( array(  
     'type'      => 'checkbox',
     'post_id'   => $object_id, 
     'id'     => 'wcv_custom_product__wc_security_deposits_enable', 
     'label'    => __( 'Ingredients', 'wcvendors-pro' ), 
     'placeholder'   => __( 'Ingredients', 'wcvendors-pro' ), 
     'desc_tip'    => 'true', 
     'description'   => __( 'Enable this to collect a security deposit for this product', 'wcvendors-pro' ), 
) );
```

Add this to your product-edit.php template. Override the template and place it in your themes directory. See my documentation on how to override templates here:

https://docs.wcvendors.com/knowledge-base/changing-the-vendor-templates/